# UICollectionView ReloadData not showing content properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

I am trying to filter my homeCollectionView with SegmentControl. On taping on the segment, I am filtering the content based on tag available in the dictionary. When I am performing ReloadData and switching between the segments, in the first go (when I am taping on the segments the first time), the filter is working and all data is coming, but when I tap back on the segments, part of the content in the cell, especially the LabelViews text are not showing up afterwards. Also, it's happening for random indexPath.

This is my code:

```
@objc func toggleHomeContent(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    toggleValContType = notification.object as? String ?? "all"

    if (toggleValContType == "all") {
        mainArrayData = primaryArrayData
    }
    else if (toggleValContType == "collections") {
        mainArrayData = primaryArrayData { $0["filterType"] == "Col" || $0["filterType"] == "CTA" }
    }
    else if (toggleValContType == "books") {
        mainArrayData = primaryArrayData { $0["filterType"] == "Book" || $0["filterType"] == "CTA" }
    }

    homeCollectionView?.reloadData()
    homeCollectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    homeCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    //DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: homeCollectionView.reloadData)
}
```

And by arrays are declared like this:

```
var mainArrayData   : [[String:String]] = HomeArray().mainArray
var primaryArrayData: [[String:String]] = HomeArray().mainArray
```

Heres the snapshot of what the issue is:

[Snapshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISMzq.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in main thread  :

```
 homeCollectionView?.reloadData()
homeCollectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
 homeCollectionView?.reloadData()
homeCollectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the solution is not solving the issue. It is still reloading with blank LableViews.

Comment: Please have a look on the Snapshot I added with the issue.

Comment: use
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezjY4.png 

3D view hierarchy inspection built in tool check the uiview is not breaking the constraints.

Comment: and if there everything showing fine only label text is missing then again recheck you cellForRowForItem code.

Comment: Thank a lot for the information. That actually worked and I was able to understand that the label was not getting generated due to height constraint. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: your welcome and also please mark this answer helpful!!! It will be appreciated.